# Why don't I get anything from this API call?

Tags: rest, web, postman, screen-scraping, insomnia

I'm trying to get a the JSON received from this API https://70aidzp7ck-2.algolianet.com/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(4.14.2)%3B%20Browser%20(lite)%3B%20instantsearch.js%20(4.49.1)%3B%20JS%20Helper%20(3.11.1)&x-algolia-api-key=a4a35644550d8855512297e93a18e30a&x-algolia-application-id=70AIDZP7CK

I copied it directly to postman and I get a 400, I've also tried copying the cUrl still the same issue. Any idea why I'm not able to replicate the request using postman? This is a POST request.

Comment: A 400 response is an error and a 200 response is a success. A 500 response is an internal error.

Comment: I rolled back your last edit because the answer doesn't belong in the question. On this site, [we maintain a strict separation between questions and answers](/tour). If you've found the solution to your own problem, that's great! Please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) in the space for an answer below.

Comment: i solved my issue by adding the payload/body to the request